# Plotting power spectrum in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I have an array with 301 values, which were gathered from a movie clip with 301 frames. This means 1 value from 1 frame. The movie clip is running at 30 fps, so is in fact 10 sec long

Now I would like to get the power spectrum of this "signal" ( with the right Axis). I tried:

```
 X = fft(S_[:,2]);
 pl.plot(abs(X))
 pl.show()
```

I also tried:

```
 X = fft(S_[:,2]);
 pl.plot(abs(X)**2)
 pl.show()
```

Though I don't think this is the real spectrum.

the signal:
[image]

The spectrum: [image]

The power spectrum :

[image]

Can anyone provide some help with this ? **I would like to have a plot in Hz**.

Comment: Why you *"don't think this is the real spectrum"* ?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Numpy has a convenience function, `np.fft.fftfreq` to compute the frequencies associated with FFT components:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(301) - 0.5
ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(data))**2

time_step = 1 / 30
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(data.size, time_step)
idx = np.argsort(freqs)

plt.plot(freqs[idx], ps[idx])
```

[image]

Note that the largest frequency you see in your case is not 30 Hz, but

```
In [7]: max(freqs)
Out[7]: 14.950166112956811
```

You never see the sampling frequency in a power spectrum. If you had had an even number of samples, then you would have reached the [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency), 15 Hz in your case (although numpy would have calculated it as -15).

Comment: In your comment above, should the frequencies have Hz units rather than the kHz units you have used?

Comment: What are the x- and y-axis labels in this case?

Comment: The x axis label would be Hz and the y axis label would be the square of the units of the data. For instance, if the data has a unit m/s, then the power spectra would be (m/s)^2.

Comment: @Arun, the units of power spectral density is SI^2 / Hz. So if the data is m/s, the y unit is (m/s)^2 / Hz.

Answer (score 24):

if rate is the sampling rate(Hz), then `np.linspace(0, rate/2, n)` is the frequency array of every point in fft. You can use `rfft` to calculate the fft in your data is real values:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
rate = 30.0
t = np.arange(0, 10, 1/rate)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*4*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*7*t) + np.random.randn(len(t))*0.2
p = 20*np.log10(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x)))
f = np.linspace(0, rate/2, len(p))
plot(f, p)
```

[image]

signal x contains 4Hz & 7Hz sin wave, so there are two peaks at 4Hz & 7Hz.

Comment: A small correction, when using `fft.rfft`: `p[0] -= 6.02; p[-1] -= 6.02` (`absfft2[0] /= 2; absfft2[-1] /= 2`) -- see e.g. Numerical Recipes p. 653

Comment: I think the last line should be `pl.plot(f, p)` in order to run the code . And thank you for your answer it is very didactic.

Comment: If you're using `np.fft.frrt`, the corresponding function for the frequencies is `np.fft.rfftfreq`

Answer (score 14):

You can also use [scipy.signal.welch](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) to estimate the power spectral density using Welch’s method.
Here is an comparison between np.fft.fft and scipy.signal.welch:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 10e3
N = 1e5
amp = 2*np.sqrt(2)
freq = 1234.0
noise_power = 0.001 * fs / 2
time = np.arange(N) / fs
x = amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*freq*time)
x += np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(noise_power), size=time.shape)

# np.fft.fft
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(time.size, 1/fs)
idx = np.argsort(freqs)
ps = np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))**2
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freqs[idx], ps[idx])
plt.title('Power spectrum (np.fft.fft)')

# signal.welch
f, Pxx_spec = signal.welch(x, fs, 'flattop', 1024, scaling='spectrum')
plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(f, np.sqrt(Pxx_spec))
plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('Linear spectrum [V RMS]')
plt.title('Power spectrum (scipy.signal.welch)')
plt.show()
```

[[image: fft[2]]
[image: welch]

Comment: might be good to compare `rfft` instead of `fft`

Comment: New link to the latest documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/signal.html#spectral-analysis-using-welch-s-method

Answer (score 6):

From the numpy fft page http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html:

> When the input a is a time-domain signal and A = fft(a), np.abs(A) is
>   its amplitude spectrum and np.abs(A)**2 is its power spectrum. The
>   phase spectrum is obtained by np.angle(A).

Comment: I added the plot with np.abs(A)**2. Though, how can I plot it so that I can seen the Hz ? I doubt it goes from 0 to 301 Hz, when I have exactly 301 samples :P

Comment: you have to do yourself: FFT does know only about equally spaced data (like on a regular grid), not physical quantities.

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth taking a log10 of the result values to get a result in dB?

Answer (score 6):

Since FFT is symmetric over it's centre, half the values are just enough.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 30.0
t = np.arange(0,10,1/fs)
x = np.cos(2*np.pi*10*t)

xF = np.fft.fft(x)
N = len(xF)
xF = xF[0:N/2]
fr = np.linspace(0,fs/2,N/2)

plt.ion()
plt.plot(fr,abs(xF)**2)
```

Comment: Generally FFT is not symmetric.
np.fft.rfft should work faster and with less resource utilization in your case..